# iOs 13 and horizontal scroll: native lazy loading?

Tags: ios, css, safari

I'm encountering a strange issue only on Safari iOs 13. I have an element which has horizontal scroll (native scroll, `overflow-x: auto`).
On iOs 13, when I scroll this area, when an element outside the viewport comes in the viewport, first it's hidden, then flickers and becomes visible.

Here's a screencast of this issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jvQy.jpg

You can see it live: https://www.thebackpackerz.com/agenda/concerts-rap-paris/

My guess is that's related to iOs 13 new features :

> Added support for one-finger accelerated scrolling to all frames and
>   overflow:scroll elements eliminating the need to
>   set-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch.
>
> Changed the default behavior on iPad for wide web pages with
>   responsive meta-tags that require horizontal scrolling. Pages are
>   scaled to prevent horizontal scrolling and any text is resized to
>   preserve legibility.

But well, right now, it's like a bug to me. Any idea to patch this?

Comment: The images are local or downloaded?

Comment: You can see it in the link I provided. Images comes from the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and after trying different solutions i came up with this.

```
.bottom-nav-wrapper {
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
     overflow-x: scroll;
     overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

And in this wrapper you can place your cards/elements for horizontal scrolling.